# Parallel Synchronized Iterative Tasks in Native C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, parallel-processing, native

I am using Native C++ (no .Net or /clr) and would like to do this, if possible, without or with minimal dependence on external or 3rd party libraries, which is where I'm stuck.

To break my question down to be as to the point as possible, consider three functions task1(), task2(), and task3(). Each are part of a step in an iterative process, i.e.:

```
    while(true)
    {
      task1();
      task2();
      task3();
    }
```

I'm looking for a way to execute task1() and task(3) in parallel. To restate this, the following is the allowable parallelization:

start -> task1() -> task2() -> { task3() & task1() in parallel } -> task2() -> { task3() & task1() in parallel } -> task2() -> { task3() & task1() in parallel } -> task2() -> etc.

Any help is appreciated, and as I stated I'd like to not really on any 3rd party libraries and stay in native C++11.

Comment: You might be looking for [`std::async`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async)

Comment: Search the web for "C++ Boost Threads".

Comment: Do you want true parallel processing (such as one thread on each core at the same time)?  There is no guarantee that your threads will execute in parallel or that they will be run on separate cores, unless you can convince your OS to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A naive approach could be like this (only the repeating part):

```
while (true)
{
    task2();
    std::thread t1(task1), t3(task3);
    t1.join();
    t3.join();
}
```

It may or may not be worth spinning up threads every time. You may like to keep two threads permanently alive and pass work items into them. This is in fact one possible implementation for `std::async`, though generally you don't have a whole lot of control over how `async` schedules its work:

```
while (true)
{
    task2();
    auto f1 = std::async(task1), f3(task3);
    f1.get();
    f3.get();
}
```

Comment: Maybe a better approach would be to start the threads before the `while` loop and *feed* them inside the loop.  This eliminates that good old overhead of creating and destroying threads.

Comment: +1 This got me on the right track. I will temporarily implement your second suggestion, but I haven't found anything in documentation indicating that std::async isn't taking time to create new threads.

I figured probably the more correct solution is to create three threads that stay alive and synchronize them at each iteration but this is certainly simpler.

Comment: @RussellTrahan: You can write your own little thread pool for that, and then use it like so: `while (true) { pool.flush(); task2(); pool.enqueue(task1); pool.enqueue(task3); }`

Comment: Exactly what I think I wanted! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a library to help you with this. Would you please check out [Cpp-Taskflow](https://github.com/cpp-taskflow/cpp-taskflow)?